# Wakeword Engine Porcupine with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, audio, speech

I'm trying to set up a wake word detection in my ASP.NET MVC app. I've read the documentation for wakeword on .NET several times over (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Porcupine/#readme-body-tab) and I think I've satisfied all of the requirements ,using a window 64 bits machine, on a .NET Framework 4.6.1+ (since ASP.NET MVC technically in 6.0), access key... but I think there's still a concept that I've not quite grasp so I can't seem to get it working despite doing search and viewing documentation everywhere.

Below is the part of code that is causing issue for me and everything else run great, it's just that the wake word part (`handle.Process(GetNextAudioFrame)`) won't recognize what I say, either because I didn't know how to paste in the right audio frame for it or I messed up somewhere

```
List<BuiltInKeyword> keyword = new List<BuiltInKeyword> { BuiltInKeyword.ALEXA };

try  // (there is a catch below but these are not part of the problem)
{
    Porcupine handle = Porcupine.FromBuiltInKeywords(accessKey, keyword);  // now just got to determine when wakeword executed
            
    while (true)
    {
        short[] GetNextAudioFrame = new short[handle.FrameLength];
        var keywordIndex = handle.Process(GetNextAudioFrame);
        // ...
    }
}
```

The documents for this part mentioned the Sample Rate as well as the Framelength to which I assume is what I'm missing but I can't figure out what to do next even after looking at the demo since it's technically did the short[] this way instead of what was shown in the document:

```
short[] GetNextAudioFrame = new short[handle.FrameLength];
```

[image: documentation]

Has anyone experienced setting this up before? Or could you tell me what is that Sample rate and frame length I'm missing is about and perhaps I could start going from there? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

```
short[] GetNextAudioFrame = new short[handle.FrameLength];
var keywordIndex = handle.Process(GetNextAudioFrame);
```

You are creating an empty array and passing that array of 0s to Porcupine.

For wake word detection to work, it needs some real audio data to process. You either need to record audio with a microphone or read an audio file and pass the audio data to the engine. The audio file/recording needs to be at the sample rate specified by the engine (in this case 16000Hz) and the audio data needs to be broken up into arrays of size equal to the frame length (in this case 512).

There are .NET demos on Picovoice's GitHub demonstrating recording from a microphone and reading from an audio file. I'd recommend checking them out!

https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/tree/master/demo/dotnet/PorcupineDemo

Comment: Ah, that'd make sense then. I've found a youtube demonstration for this but it still make me wonder how it really work, tysm!